# PySpark Dataframe to Json - grouping data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to create a json from a dataframe. Please find the dataframe below,

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    CustId|                 TIN|EntityType|    EntityAttributes|AddressPreference|      AddressDetails|EmailPreference|        EmailDetails|PhonePreference|        PhoneDetails|       MemberDetails|
+----------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1234567890|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...|    Person|[{null, PRINCESS,...|        Alternate|[{Home, 460 M XXX...|        Primary|[{Home, HEREBY...|      Alternate|[{Home, {88888888...|[{7777777, 999999...|
|1234567890|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...|    Person|[{null, PRINCESS,...|        Alternate|[{Home, 460 M XXX...|        Primary|[{Home, HEREBY...|        Primary|[{Home, {88888888...|[{7777777, 999999...|
|1234567890|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...|    Person|[{null, PRINCESS,...|          Primary|[{Home, PO BOX 695020...|        Primary|[{Home, HEREBY...|      Alternate|[{Home, {88888888...|[{7777777, 999999...|
|1234567890|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...|    Person|[{null, PRINCESS,...|          Primary|[{Home, PO BOX 695020...|        Primary|[{Home, HEREBY...|        Primary|[{Home, {88888888...|[{7777777, 999999...|
+----------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

So the initial columns custid, TIN, Entitytype,EntityAttributes will be same for a particular customer, say 1234567890 in our example. But he might be having multiple addresses/phone/email. Could you please help us on how to group them under 1 json.

Expected Structure :

{
"CustId": 1234567890,
"TIN": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"EntityType": "Person",
"EntityAttributes": [
{
"FirstName": "PRINCESS",
"LastName": "XXXXXX",
"BirthDate": "xxxx-xx-xx",
"DeceasedFlag": "False"
}
],
"Address": [
{
"AddressPreference": "Alternate",
"AddressDetails": {
"AddressType": "Home",
"Address1": "460",
"City": "XXXX",
"State": "XXX",
"Zip": "XXXX"
}
},
{
"AddressPreference": "Primary",
"AddressDetails": {
"AddressType": "Home",
"Address1": "PO BOX 695020",
"City": "XXX",
"State": "XXXX",
"Zip": "695020",
}
}
],
"Phone": [
{
"PhonePreference": "Primary",
"PhoneDetails": {
"PhoneType": "Home",
"PhoneNumber": "xxxxx",
"FormatPhoneNumber": "xxxxxx"
}
},
{
"PhonePreference": "Alternate",
"PhoneDetails": {
"PhoneType": "Home",
"PhoneNumber": "xxxx",
"FormatPhoneNumber": "xxxxx"
}
},
{

```
],
"Email": [
    {
        "EmailPreference": "Primary",
        "EmailDetails": {
            "EmailType": "Home",
            "EmailAddress": "xxxxxxx@GMAIL.COM"
        }
    }
],
    }
]
```

}

**UPDATE**

Tried with the below recommended group by method, it ended up giving 1 customer details, but the email is repeated 4 times in the list. Ideally it should be having only 1 email. Also In the Address Preference Alternate has 1 address and primary has 1 address, but the Alternate shows 2 entries and primary shows 2.  Could you please help with an ideal solution.

Comment: what is expected output here ?

Comment: @dsk : The expected output is a json with 1 entry for customerid,tin,entitytpe and prefernce and 2 entries for address(1 alterate and 1 primary) and 1 entry for email..

Comment: @SnehaNair Instead of `collect_list` use `collect_set` to de-duplicate the data

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should work. `id` is like a `custid` in your example which has repeating values.

```
>>> df.show()
+----+------------+----------+
|  id|     address|     email|
+----+------------+----------+
|1001|   address-a|   email-a|
|1001|   address-b|   email-b|
|1002|address-1002|email-1002|
|1003|address-1003|email-1002|
|1002|   address-c|   email-2|
+----+------------+----------+
```

Aggregate on those repeating columns and then convert to JSON

```
>>> results = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("address").alias("address"),collect_list("email").alias("email")).toJSON().collect()
>>> for i in results: print(i)
... 
{"id":"1003","address":["address-1003"],"email":["email-1002"]}
{"id":"1002","address":["address-1002","address-c"],"email":["email-1002","email-2"]}
{"id":"1001","address":["address-a","address-b"],"email":["email-a","email-b"]}
```

Comment: But in this case, the logic is creating 4 entries for email. This example has only 1 email and only that should be displayed for 1 customer..  Could you please help

Comment: Use `collect_set` in place of `collect_list` to avoid duplication

Comment: Its not working as required, could you please check this question, I have re-framed the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295955/dataframe-grouping-on-a-column-and-alias