# Dataframe Grouping on a column and alias

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to create a Dataframe from a table content like this,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_distinct, sequence
dfMem = spark.sql(f"select * from curate.Final_Record MH WHERE MH.partyid in ( 111111)")
df = dfMem.select(
    "CustId",
    "TIN",
    "EntityType",
    F.struct(
      F.col("PhonePreference"),
      F.struct(
        F.col("PhoneType"),
        F.col("PhoneNumber"),
        F.col("FormatPhoneNumber"),
      ).alias("PhoneDetails")
  ).alias("Phone"),
).groupBy(
    "CustId",
    "TIN",
    "EntityType",
).agg(
    
    
    F.collect_list("Phone").alias("Phone"),
    
)
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df = df.withColumn("Phone", array_distinct("Phone"))
```

and this is the json output,

```
{
    "CustId": 1234567890,
    "TIN": "xxxxx",
    "EntityType": "Person",
    "Phone": [
        {
            "PhonePreference": "Primary",
            "PhoneDetails": {
                "PhoneType": "Home",
                "PhoneNumber": "111111111",
                "FormatPhoneNumber": "(111)111-1111"
            }
        },
        {
            "PhonePreference": "Primary",
            "PhoneDetails": {
                "PhoneType": "Work",
                "PhoneNumber": "2222222222",
                "FormatPhoneNumber": "(222)222-2222"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We need help and are trying to group the phone number based on the phonepreference , so output should ideally be like this

```
{
    "CustId": 1234567890,
    "TIN": "xxxxx",
    "EntityType": "Person",
    "Phone": [
        "PhonePreference": "Primary",
        {
            "PhoneDetails": {
                "PhoneType": "Home",
                "PhoneNumber": "111111111",
                "FormatPhoneNumber": "(111)111-1111"
            }
        },
        {
            "PhoneDetails": {
                "PhoneType": "Work",
                "PhoneNumber": "2222222222",
                "FormatPhoneNumber": "(222)222-2222"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We tried group by on the phonepreference and created a df for phone, but that is making the code lengthy. Also there are more blocks called email,address etc which will make the code blocks bulky. Also we need to have the alias called Phone, then the preference type and then the 2 numbers under them, which wasnt achievable.
Could you please suggest some good alternative?

Comment: Do you have the input data in tabular format to share here ?>

Comment: Solved this by grouping addressdetails and aggregating them again using collect_set